# Symantec cloud antivirus now blocks Git, SSH, Cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin, anti-virus

I run Symantec Cloud Antivirus on Windows.  Recently, after an upgrade, it started blocking SSH, Git, Cygwin.  In particular, it deletes git, says it fails a SONAR Heuristic, and doesn't seem to give me any way to override it!

How can I use git if I have Symantec antivirus? Or at least mark git as safe?

Comment: What did you research tell you? Couldn't you find [Creating exceptions for Virus and Spyware scans](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO80919.html)?

Comment: @DavidPostill: You should post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @JaySullivan I only post answers when I know them to be correct. I don't use Symantic so I can't test it. That's why I left it as a comment.